# Passing large array to the next page using session in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

Here is my loop

```
foreach($values['searchresult']['hotel'] as $key=>$items){

     //setup the array for booking page
      $data[$key]=$items['roomDetails'];      
     $this->session->set_userdata('room_details',$data);
    <a href="'.base_url().'book/'.$key.'">Book</a>
}
```

In this i will get the each room details in `book` view like this way

```
public function room_details($key){
   $data=$this->session->userdata('roomDetails');
  /* for a particular room*/
   print_r($data[$key]);
  //populate the data in the view
  $this->load->view('book-now',$data);
}
```

Its works fine, but its a **large array i don't know my method is correct or not is any other way to do this efficiently**?

Comment: do you really need a large array of room details in the session? can't you just select where the details of that particular key on demand?

Comment: Actually it contains only the  necessary data for booking ,but its a large array.

Answer (score 1):

All sessions are stored on the server. You can store as much data as you like .
the maximum memory a script can consume at one time is default 128MB,which the limit you can reach.

Comment: here is no restriction on length imposed by CodeIgniter. The only restriction is set by the field you chose to use to save the data in your database.

Comment: Nop the session data is limited to 4kb in codeigniter

Comment: i can use php Standerd session,but i think its not a better idea

Comment: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html the 4K limit is only for cookies. Use sessions

Answer (score 0):

**In Codeigniter**

It is not a good method to store dynamic mysql results to session variables.
Because
**We cannot predict the dynamic size of arrays or values resulted by sql query.**

Use/Execute sql queries to get data instead of sessions. But username,id,status etc having limited size can be stored in sessions.

In the documentation regarding CI Sessions there is a size limitation for the amount of data stored in the session object. And as per RFC 2109 this size limit is 4KB

visit http://forum.codeigniter.com/archive/index.php?thread-7145.html